# ImageView stick to UILabel in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, snapkit

I have problem to achieve this on SnapKit, I want that my ImageView should be stick to multi-line UILabel in UITableViewCell

It should work like on this image:

[image]

I tried something like this and this approach not working.

```
label.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.top.left.equalToSuperview()
}

imageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
     make.size.equalTo(20.0)
     make.top.equalToSuperview()
     make.left.equalTo(label.snp.right).offset(5)
     make.right.greaterThanOrEqualToSuperview()
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: you have shown what you want to achieve but havent shown what you are currently receiving..

Comment: Currently ImageView is always on the right without stick to UILabel

Comment: have you tried make.right.lessThanOrEqualToSuperview()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image view should have: `make.right.lessThanOrEqualToSuperview()` so that it doesn't have to go all the way to the right of the superview, (which is probably centering your image somewhere between the label and the right of the superview, instead of floating to the left).

Comment: No problem, can you mark my answer as the solution to your problem?